# select all attributes and its value for a given node-Linq to xml

Tags: asp.net, xml, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I have an xml file that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Content>
  <Field Title="XYZ">
    <Description>Numeric</Description>
    <Comment>12345</Comment>
  </Field>
<Field Title="ABC">
    <Description>Alphabetic</Description>
    <Comment>QWERTY</Comment>
  </Field>
<Field Title="XYZ">
    <Description>Alphabetic</Description>
    <Comment>QWERTY</Comment>
  </Field>
</Content>
```

I want to extract Node values of `<Description>` and `<Comment>`
that comes under attribute `Title` with `Value='XYZ'`

I tried something like this using Linq to Xml , but not getting expecting result

```
string Xmlpath = @"d:\Test.xml";
XDocument mappings = XDocument.Load(Xmlpath);
var Data = from elm in mappings.Descendants("Field")
           where (string)elm.Attribute("Title") == "XYZ"
           select elm;
```

Can somebody help me ?

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a collection with all those elements as you specified:

```
 var result = XDocument.Load(XmlPath).Root
                       .Descendants("Field")
                       .Where(element => element.Attribute("Title") == "XYZ")
                       .Descendants()
                       .Where(element => element.Name == "Description" || 
                                         element.Name == "Comment")
                       .Select(element => element.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: Note that `?.` is C# 6.0 and OP tagged the question with C# 4.0.

Comment: The code that OP uses is also safe from NRE : `(string)elm.Attribute("Title") == "XYZ"`

Answer (score 0):

You have managed to get `<Field>` elements that match the 'Title' attribute value criteria in the `Data` variable. Next, you can use `Element()` to get child element of the `<Field>` :

```
var result = Data.FirstOrDefault();
if(result != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)result.Element("Description"));
    Console.WriteLine((string)result.Element("Comment"));
}
```

Or, using `foreach` if there can be multiple `<Field>` elements matching the criteria :

```
foreach(result in Data)
{
    Console.WriteLine((string)result.Element("Description"));
    Console.WriteLine((string)result.Element("Comment"));
}
```